# How do I remove duplicate characters and keep the unique one only in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, string, duplicates

How do I remove duplicate characters and keep the unique one only.
For example,  my input is:

```
EFUAHUU
UUUEUUUUH
UJUJHHACDEFUCU
```

Expected output is:

```
EFUAH
UEH
UJHACDEF
```

I came across `perl -pe's/$1//g while/(.).*\/'` which is wonderful but it is removing even the single occurrence of the character in output.

Answer (score 15):

This can be done using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
perl -pe 's/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g' FILE_NAME
```

The regex used is: `(.)(?=.*?\1)`

- `.` : to match any char.
- first `()` : remember the matched
  single char.
- `(?=...)` : +ve lookahead
- `.*?` : to match anything in between
- `\1` : the remembered match.
- `(.)(?=.*?\1)` : match and remember
  any char ***only if*** it appears again
  later in the string.
- `s///` : Perl way of doing the
  substitution.
- `g`: to do the substitution
  globally...that is don't stop after
  first substitution.
- `s/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g` : this will
  delete a char from the input string
  only if that char appears again later
  in the string.

This will ***not*** maintain the order of the char in the input because for every unique char in the input string, we retain its ***last*** occurrence and not the ***first***.

To keep the relative order intact we can do what `KennyTM` tells in one of the comments:

- reverse the input line
- do the substitution as before
- reverse the result before printing

The Perl one line for this is:

```
perl -ne '$_=reverse;s/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g;print scalar reverse;' FILE_NAME
```

Since we are doing `print` manually after reversal, we don't use the `-p` flag but use the `-n` flag.

I'm not sure if this is the best one-liner to do this. I welcome others to edit this answer if they have a better alternative.

Comment: @Gavin: That can be fixed by reversing the string initially, and reverse the string after the replacement.

Comment: Well this is amazing !!!!
But can you explain me bit details like 
what ===>  s/(.) and (?=.*?\1)// is doing ?
Also is it possible to have in the same order which I have put in my early query , For ex. currently I am getting EFAHU  instead of EFUAH which is more helpful.

Thnax a ton :)

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks :) @Manu: I've updated my ans with a short explanation of whats going on.

Comment: This is working exactly. Thanx again for the kind reply and clear explanation of all the stuff.
Thank u all :)

Answer (score 5):

if Perl is not a must, you can also use awk. here's a fun benchmark on the Perl one liners posted against awk. awk is 10+ seconds faster for a file with 3million++ lines

```
$ wc -l <file2
3210220

$ time awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{delete _;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(!_[$i]++) printf $i};print""}' file2 >/dev/null

real    1m1.761s
user    0m58.565s
sys     0m1.568s

$ time perl -n -e '%seen=();' -e 'for (split //) {print unless $seen{$_}++;}'  file2 > /dev/null

real    1m32.123s
user    1m23.623s
sys     0m3.450s

$ time perl -ne '$_=reverse;s/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g;print scalar reverse;' file2 >/dev/null

real    1m17.818s
user    1m10.611s
sys     0m2.557s

$ time perl -ne'my%s;print grep!$s{$_}++,split//' file2 >/dev/null

real    1m20.347s
user    1m13.069s
sys     0m2.896s
```

Comment: I am amazed of how fast the regexp solution is

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -ne'my%s;print grep!$s{$_}++,split//'
```

Comment: This is also working and shorter than earlier one. I am overwhelmed by the response :)
I would like to know its working if possible.

Comment: It works in same way as gianthare solution but much more idiomatic Perl and faster.

Comment: A nice one, I agree. Almost a one-liner except for the `my %s`. Though I don't see where the speedup is coming from. May it be from fresh hashtable instead of resetting? Or is grep more efficient than the explicit loop?

Comment: @gianthare: there is difference calling `print` for each character and calling `print` with array parameter. Your code will be slower for lines with bigger amount of unique chars. `%seen=();` should be almost same fast as mine `my %s;`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, that I think should work faster than the lookahead one, but is not regexp-based and uses hashtable.

```
perl -n -e '%seen=();' -e 'for (split //) {print unless $seen{$_}++;}'
```

It splits every line into characters and prints only the first appearance by counting appearances inside %seen hashtable

Answer (score 1):

Tie::IxHash is a good module to store hash order (but may be slow, you will need to benchmark if speed is important). Example with tests:

```
use Test::More 0.88;

use Tie::IxHash;
sub dedupe {
  my $str=shift;
  my $hash=Tie::IxHash->new(map { $_ => 1} split //,$str);
  return join('',$hash->Keys);
}

{
my $str='EFUAHUU';
is(dedupe($str),'EFUAH');
}

{
my $str='EFUAHHUU';
is(dedupe($str),'EFUAH');
}

{
my $str='UJUJHHACDEFUCU';
is(dedupe($str),'UJHACDEF');
}

done_testing();
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic application of positive lookbehind, but unfortunately perl doesn't support that. In fact, doing this (matching the preceding text of a character in a string with a full regex whose length is indeterminable) can only be done with .NET regex classes, I think.

However, positive lookahead supports full regexes, so all you need to do is reverse the string, apply positive lookahead (like unicornaddict said):

```
perl -pe 's/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g'
```

And reverse it back, because without the reverse that'll only keep the duplicate character at the last place in a line.

**MASSIVE EDIT**

I've been spending the last half an hour on this, and this looks like this works, **without the reversing**.

```
perl -pe 's/\G$1//g while (/(.).*(?=\1)/g)' FILE_NAME
```

I don't know whether to be proud or horrified. I'm basically doing the positive looakahead, then substituting on the string with \G specified - which makes the regex engine start its matching from the last place matched (internally represented by the pos() variable).

With test input like this:

> aabbbcbbccbabb
>
> EFAUUUUH
>
> ABCBBBBD
>
> DEEEFEGGH
>
> AABBCC

The output is like this:

> abc
>
> EFAUH
>
> ABCD
>
> DEFGH
>
> ABC

I *think* it's working...

*Explanation* - Okay, in case my explanation last time wasn't clear enough - the lookahead will go and stop at the last match of a duplicate variable [in the code you can do a print pos(); inside the loop to check] and the s/\G//g will remove it [you don't need the /g really]. So within the loop, the substitution will continue removing until all such duplicates are zapped. Of course, this might be a little too processor intensive for your tastes... but so are most of the regex-based solutions you'll see. The reversing/lookahead method will probably be more efficient than this, though.

Comment: More precisely, it's *variable-length* lookbehinds Perl doesn't support.  Besides .NET, they're supported by JGSoft (EditPad Pro, PowerGrep) and in more limited form by Java.

Comment: Edited and added new solution. Not sure if it's fullproof or not... too much caffeine. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Use uniq from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~vparseval/List-MoreUtils-0.22/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm):

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -ne 'print uniq split ""'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the set of characters that can be encountered is restricted, e.g. only letters, then the easiest solution will be with tr
`perl -p -e 'tr/a-zA-Z/a-zA-Z/s'`
It will replace all the letters by themselves, leaving other characters unaffected and /s modifier will squeeze repeated occurrences of the same character (after replacement), thus removing duplicates

**Me bad - it removes only adjoining appearances. Disregard**

Answer (score 0):

for a file containing the data you list named foo.txt

```
python -c "print set(open('foo.txt').read())"
```

Comment: His original post did not specify perl as a requirement (though he tagged it perl), only pointed out he found a perl one-liner as a possible way to do it. He also did not say order mattered, only uniqueness. Also, the use of a one-liner indicates that the method doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

From the shell, this works:

```
sed -e 's/$/<EOL>/ ; s/./&\n/g' test.txt | uniq | sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n//; ta ; s/<EOL>/\n/g'
```

In words: mark every linebreak with a `<EOL>` string, then put every character on a line of its own, then use `uniq` to remove duplicate lines, then strip out all the linebreaks, then put back linebreaks instead of the `<EOL>` markers.

I found the `-e :a -e '$!N; s/\n//; ta` part in a forum post and I don't understand the seperate `-e :a` part, or the `$!N` part, so if anyone can explain those, I'd be grateful.

Hmm, that one does only *consecutive* duplicates; to eliminate *all* duplicates you could do this:

```
cat test.txt | while read line ; do echo $line | sed -e 's/./&\n/g' | sort | uniq | sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n//; ta' ; done
```

That puts the characters in each line in alphabetical order though.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($uniq, $seq, @result);
$uniq ='';
sub uniq {
    $seq = shift;
    for (split'',$seq) {
    $uniq .=$_ unless $uniq =~ /$_/;
    }
    push @result,$uniq;
    $uniq='';
}

while(<DATA>){
   uniq($_);
}
print @result;

__DATA__
EFUAHUU
UUUEUUUUH
UJUJHHACDEFUCU
```

The output:

```
EFUAH
UEH
UJHACDEF
```