# php regex how to remove duplicate charactors and make every charactor unique in string

Tags: php, regex

How should one use `preg_replace()` to replace a string from 'aabbaacc' to 'abc'?

Currently, my code uses  `str_split()` then `array_unique()` then `implode()`.
I think `preg_replace()` can achieve this also, but I don't know how.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: FWIW, I like your method.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723389/remove-repeating-character

Comment: @NickFury Actually, now that I think about this, that regex will only catch duplicates in sequence. Not if they appear later in the string. As a result, `aabbaacc` would become `abac` instead of `abc`, I believe.

Comment: thanks nick, the method in your post will return 'abac', but not 'abc',

Comment: Ignore that possible dup as @ColinMorelli pointed out, it's not the same question.

Comment: @ColinMorelli i may not be an expert, but i at least know a little about programming. I benchmarked both the "3 loops" code and your function, and it turns out that the "3 loops" is about 3x faster than your function. Sorry to disapoint you though :)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Because you ran it with the string in question here (and also probably don't know how to benchmark). Which is an _extremely_ unlikely scenario. I benchmarked the same thing using a long string, which is considerably more likely to be used in a real world application. You may look at the code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5dec0188d383742dfc46a9222bd221f86a3ccd7) and run it your self. My method (the first) is clearly faster. Benchmarking unrealistic inputs is a complete waste of everyone's time. Go ahead, feel free to change the string and test again

Comment: @ColinMorelli weird ... I saw the results online and yes your function is faster, but when i try it on my localhost the 3loops is about x3 faster even when i put some other long string o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex that seems to work for me is `/(.)(?=.*?\1)/`. Please test it for yourself here:

http://regexpal.com/

I've also tested it with `preg_replace('/(.)(?=.*?\1)/', '', 'aaabbbabc')` which returns the expected `abc`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the order of appearance of the charactere?

Using the provided regex: `bbbaaacccabc` => `abc`
What if I want `bac`?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. It takes the last occurrence of every character, not the first one. The suggestion behind your link is okay, I can't think of a way to do that with only regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
$string = 'dbbaabbbaac';

$new = preg_replace_callback( array("/(.)\\1+/"),function($M){print_r($M);return $M[1];}, $string  );
$new = preg_replace_callback( array('/(.)(.?\\1)/i','/(.)(.*?\\1)/i'),function($M){return $M[1].trim($M[2],$M[1]);}, $new  );
echo $new."\n";
```

output

```
dbac
```

or this with out Regex

```
$value="aabbaacc";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($value);$i++){
    $out[$value[$i]]=$value[$i];
}
echo implode("",$out);
```

output:

```
abc
```

Comment: `$out` should be declared as an array

Comment: @ColinMorelli  didn't need to declared as array , php support this syntax

Comment: Just because PHP supports it, doesn't mean you should do it. PHP also supports `eval`

Comment: @user995789 I do it by Two level Regex

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I got.  However, it's basically a copy of :
[How do I remove duplicate characters and keep the unique one only in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582940/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-characters-and-keep-the-unique-one-only-in-perl)

```
<?php
    $string = 'aabbaacc';

    $new = preg_replace( '/(.)(?=.*?\1)/i','', $string  );

    echo $new;
?>
```

Unfortunately, it does not keep the string in the same order.  I don't know if that is important to you or not.