# how to use preg_replace for the following pattern

Tags: regex, string, preg-replace

Input: "abbbcdaa"  Output: "abcd"

With the follow regex the out put is abcda

```
preg_replace('/(.)\\1*/', '$1', "abbbcdaa");
```

how to get abcd using `pre_replace`

Comment: Without regex: `echo implode("", array_unique(str_split($str)));`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$string="abbbcdaa";
echo preg_replace('/(.)(?=.*?\1)/','',$string);
```

The above outputs:

```
bcda
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
echo count_chars($string,3);
```

That would also return unique characters `abcd`.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain this part of regex (?=.*?\1)

Comment: That's a look-ahead (google look-arounds). The entire regex will delete a char from the input string only if that char appears again later in the string. Also, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582940/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-characters-and-keep-the-unique-one-only-in-perl